# CASCADE Delete in many-to-many self-reference table

Tags: sql, t-sql, foreign-keys, cascade, cascading-deletes

Table **DISPLAY_TAB** below is a self-reference table that can contain both parent and child tabs. A parent tab can have multiple child tabs and a child tab can belong to multiple parents.

I'd like to establish a CASCADE DELETE relationship between main table and relationship table **DISPLAY_TAB_GROUPING** so when either parent or child tab is deleted - relationship is automatically deleted as well (just relationship, not actual tab record). So I am creating a FOREIGN KEY constrain on **DISPLAY_TAB_GROUPING** for fields TAB_ID_R_1 and TAB_ID_R_2 tables, referencing TAB_ID in **DISPLAY_TAB** table. And it works fine, it works fine when I add ON DELETE CASCADE for one of the relationship, but when I try it for both - it throws an error that this *"May cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"*.

How do I set ON CASCADE DELETE for both relationships? I don't see how this can cause cycles - every time a record in main table is deleted only related record(s) in relationship tables should be deleted.

[image]

Comment: You can use a CTE in a trigger to determine all of the related rows and delete them together.

Comment: The error message says "*may* cause cycles...", which means that technically there *is* such a possibility. A DISPLAY_TAB row could be both a child and a parent in DISPLAY_TAB_GROUPING, and deleting it would indeed cause multiple cascade paths if both ON CASCADE DELETE settings were in effect.

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for clarification, not I see. Logically a child cannot be own parent, but I can see how technically it is possible.

Comment: I meant it could be one row's parent and another's child.

Comment: @AndriyM in my case it's a one-level relationship, but I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843) KB article, which says the following among other things...

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot
>   appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential
>   actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement.
>   For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have
>   one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions
>   tree.

To do what you want, the DISPLAY_TAB_GROUPING table would have to appear twice.  I suggest you use a stored proc that implements your delete code instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid deletion in code, but looks like it's the only way.