# SQL Exception Thrown when creating a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have 2 tables, "TableA" and "TableB" setup like below.

**Table A**

```
+----------+------+---------------+
| StreamID | Name | Other Columns |
+----------+------+---------------+
```

**Table B**

```
+----+--------------+------------------------+-----------+
| ID | FileStreamID | AdditionalFileStreamID | DateAdded |
+----+--------------+------------------------+-----------+
```

Both FileStreamID and AdditionalFileStreamID in Table A are foreign key constraints to the StreamID column in Table B. I tried setting up the constraint on both columns so that when the row in Table A is deleted, the 2 columns are both set to NULL, however got a 'multiple cascade paths' exception (similar issue below):

[2 foreign key to the same table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760933/2-foreign-key-to-the-same-table-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Instead, I tried creating the following trigger to handle it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.File_Deletion_Trigger
    ON dbo.TableA
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.TableB
    SET FileStreamID = NULL
    WHERE FileStreamID IN (SELECT d.StreamID FROM deleted d)

    UPDATE dbo.TableB
    SET ScheduleStreamID = NULL
    WHERE AdditionalFileStreamID IN (SELECT d.StreamID FROM deleted d)

    DELETE FROM  dbo.TableA
    WHERE   StreamID IN (SELECT d.StreamID FROM deleted d)
END
GO
```

I am getting the following exception when I try to create the trigger:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure TableA, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
'getfileextension' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 474, Level 16, State 0, Procedure File_Deletion_Trigger, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Unable to load the computed column definitions for table "deleted".
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: That error isn't from that trigger. That suggests you have other triggers, or other SQL you aren't showing us.

Comment: From the error message text it seems like you have a problem with a computed column on `TableA` - one that uses a user defined function called `getfileextension` that doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: That clears it up a little. I'll have a look at the table and see if I can find a solution. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I think I have found where the issue lies. My TableA is an SQL file table and has a column called 'file_type'. This is a computed column with the computed text '(getfileextension([name]))'.

Comment: and it looks like file tables do not support 'INSTEAD OF' triggers. I might have to find a different way of implementing this. Cheers! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetable-compatibility-with-other-sql-server-features?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

My TableA is a file table and file tables do not support 'INSTEAD OF' triggers.

Therefore I have changed my trigger to the following and it seems to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.File_Deletion_Trigger
    ON dbo.TableA
    FOR DELETE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.TableB
    SET FileStreamID = NULL
    WHERE FileStreamID IN (SELECT d.StreamID FROM deleted d);

    UPDATE dbo.TableB
    SET AdditionalFileStreamID = NULL
    WHERE AdditionalFileStreamID IN (SELECT d.StreamID FROM deleted d);
END
GO
```