# EntityFramework CodeFirst: CASCADE DELETE for same table many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have an entry removal problem with the EntityFramework and a many-to-many relationship for the same entity. Consider this simple example:

*Entity:*

```
public class UserEntity {
    // ...
    public virtual Collection<UserEntity> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

*Fluent API Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        m.MapRightKey("FriendId");
        m.ToTable("FriendshipRelation");
    });
```

1. Am I correct, that it is not possible to define the `Cascade Delete` in Fluent API?
2. What is the best way to delete a `UserEntity`, for instance `Foo`?

   It looks for me now, I have to `Clear` the `Foo`'s `Friends` Collection, then I have to load all other `UserEntities`, which contain `Foo` in `Friends`, and then remove `Foo` from each list, before I remove `Foo` from `Users`. But it sounds too complicateda.
3. Is it possible to access the relational table directly, so that I can remove entries like this

   ```
   // Dummy code
   var query = dbCtx.Set("FriendshipRelation").Where(x => x.UserId == Foo.Id || x.FriendId == Foo.Id);
   dbCtx.Set("FriendshipRelation").RemoveRange(query);
   ```

Thank you!

***Update01:***

4. My best solution for this problem for know is just to execute the raw sql statement before I call `SaveChanges`:

   ```
   dbCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
       "delete from dbo.FriendshipRelation where UserId = @id or FriendId = @id",
       new SqlParameter("id", Foo.Id));
   ```

   But the disadvantage of this, is that, if `SaveChanges` failes for some reason, the `FriendshipRelation` are already removed and could not be rolled back. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Cascading deletes are defined in your migrations not in your fluent mappings.

Comment: @BenRobinson, hm, as I know, you can define Cascade deletes in Fluent API for `many:one` relations with `WillCascadeOnDelete` method.

Comment: @BenRobinson That is very misleading, of course cascade deletes can be configured in the fluent API

Comment: Does your sql statement  work correctly in your update1?I mean if you have friend with id=57 and Someone else has friend FriendId=57 and id=11 and again someone else(Mr x)  has FriendId=11;then when you write "delete from dbo.FriendshipRelation where UserId = 57  or FriendId = 57 ".  Mr x has friend who is not exist anymore.Am i right?

Comment: @Arashjo, actually not, if we delete a User with the ID `57`. That means we have to remove all relations to this ID in `FriendshipRelation`. That means, we remove all users friends with `UserId = 57`, AND all _other user_ relations to this user with `FriendId = 57`. With other words, we remove all my friends, and remove all relations where I am a friend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Problem 1

The answer is quite simple:

**Entity Framework cannot define cascade delete when it doesn't know which properties belong to the relationship.**

In addition, in a many:many relationship there is a third table, that is responsible for managing the relationship. This table must have at least 2 FKs. You should configure the cascade delete for each FK, not for the "entire table".

The solution is create the `FriendshipRelation` entity. Like this:

```
public class UserFriendship
{
    public int UserEntityId { get; set; } // the "maker" of the friendship

    public int FriendEntityId { get; set;  }´ // the "target" of the friendship

    public UserEntity User { get; set; } // the "maker" of the friendship

    public UserEntity Friend { get; set; } // the "target" of the friendship
}
```

Now, you have to change the `UserEntity`. Instead of a collection of `UserEntity`, it has a collection of `UserFriendship`. Like this:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<UserFriendship> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Let's see the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
    .HasKey(i => new { i.UserEntityId, i.FriendEntityId });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.User)
    .WithMany(i => i.Friends)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.UserEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); //the one

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Friend)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.FriendEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); //the one
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.UserFriendships",
    c => new
        {
            UserEntityId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            FriendEntityId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserEntityId, t.FriendEntityId })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.UserEntities", t => t.FriendEntityId, true)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.UserEntities", t => t.UserEntityId, true)
    .Index(t => t.UserEntityId)
    .Index(t => t.FriendEntityId);
```

To retrieve all user's friends:

```
var someUser = ctx.UserEntity
    .Include(i => i.Friends.Select(x=> x.Friend))
    .SingleOrDefault(i => i.UserEntityId == 1);
```

All of this works fine. However, there is a problem in that mapping (which also happens in your current mapping). Suppose that "I" am a `UserEntity`:

- I made a friend request to John -- John accepted
- I made a friend request to Ann -- Ann accepeted
- Richard made a friend request to me -- I accepted

When I retrieve my `Friends` property, it returns "John", "Ann", but not "Richard". Why? because Richard is the "maker" of the relationship not me. The `Friends` property is bound to only one side of the relationship.

Ok. How can I solve this? Easy! Change your `UserEntity` class:

```
public class UserEntity
{

    //...

    //friend request that I made
    public virtual ICollection<UserFriendship> FriendRequestsMade { get; set; }

    //friend request that I accepted
    public virtual ICollection<UserFriendship> FriendRequestsAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

Update the Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.User)
    .WithMany(i => i.FriendRequestsMade)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.UserEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Friend)
    .WithMany(i => i.FriendRequestsAccepted)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.FriendEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

There are no migrations necessary.

To retrieve all user's friends:

```
var someUser = ctx.UserEntity
    .Include(i => i.FriendRequestsMade.Select(x=> x.Friend))
    .Include(i => i.FriendRequestsAccepted.Select(x => x.User))
    .SingleOrDefault(i => i.UserEntityId == 1);
```

### Problem 2

Yes, you have to iterate the collection and remove all children objects. See my answer in this thread [Cleanly updating a hierarchy in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404672/cleanly-updating-a-hierarchy-in-entity-framework/32407776#32407776)

Following my answer, just create a `UserFriendship` dbset:

```
public DbSet<UserFriendship> UserFriendships { get; set; }
```

Now you can retrieve all friends of a specific user id, just delete all of them in one shot, and then remove the user.

### Problem 3

Yes, it is possible. You have a `UserFriendship` dbset now.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Fabio, it seem really is better to use one more table instead of the self reference, then we have much more control over the entity-relations.

Comment: You are welcome, @tenbits. Remember to mark the post as answer if it solved your problem. So, you help people in future.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't see any straightforward way to control the cascade on the many-to-many relationships using FluentApi.

2) The only available way I can think of to control that is by using the `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`, which I guess is enabled by default, at least it is for me. I just checked one of my migrations including a many-to-many relationship and indeed the `cascadeDelete: true` is there for both keys.

EDIT: Sorry, I just found that the `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` does not cover the self-referencing case. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910621/cascade-delete-in-many-to-many-self-reference-table)'s answer says that

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement. For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions tree.

So you end up having to have a custom delete code (like the sql command that you already have) and execute it in a [transaction scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

3) You should not be able to access that table from the context. Usually the table created by a many-to-many relationship is a by-product of the implementation in a relational DBMS and is considered a *weak* table respective to the related tables, which means that its rows should be cascade-deleted if one of the related entities is removed.

My advice is that, first, check if your migration is setting your table foreign keys to cascade delete. Then, if for some reason you need to restrict the deletion of a record which has related records in the many-to-many relationship, then you just check for it in your transactions.

4) In order to do that, if you really want to (FluentApi enables by default `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`), is to enclose the sql command and your SaveChanges in a transaction scope.

Comment: Thank you @Green Magic, your advice according the `transition scope` for mixing `raw SQL` and `Linq` is usefull.